# Apache Tomcat 8.5.2 + Resteasy CORS filter stops working suddenly

Tags: ajax, apache, tomcat, cors, resteasy

I have a JAX-RS application (RestEasy, 3.1.2.Final) running on an embedded Apache Tomcat (8.5.2) instance. This is a public REST service so I have added a CORS filter from RestEasy to it:

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.CorsFilter;

@Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> singletons = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        // = = = CORS = = =
        CorsFilter cors = getCorsFilter();
        singletons.add(cors);

        //...

        return singletons;
    }

    private CorsFilter getCorsFilter() {
        CorsFilter cors = new CorsFilter();
        cors.getAllowedOrigins().add("*");
        cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
        cors.setAllowedMethods("GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD");
        cors.setCorsMaxAge(1209600);
        cors.setAllowedHeaders("Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Access-Control-Request-Method,Cache-Control,Connection,Host,Referer,User-Agent");
        return cors;
    }
```

There is a security constraint defined in web.xml as well:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Tango RESTful gateway</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
            <http-method>PUT</http-method>
            <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>desy-user</role-name>
            <role-name>mtango-rest</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

In this setup everything works fine BUT for a few weeks. After a few weeks CORS preflight fails with 401 instead of normal sequence:

Request:

```
Host: mstatus.esrf.fr
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: https://ingvord.github.io
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 62
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Sun, 17 Sep 2017 07:28:19 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=85
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Obviously CORS filter is not executed anymore - there ain't response headers that it sets.

What could be the reason of a such behavior? Once again it works for a few weeks after a restart.

Application link: https://ingvord.github.io/tango-controls.demo/

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it seems the following extra configuration in web.xml has solved the issue:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>CORS preflight</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

Well, at least we do not observe any misbehavior for a quite long period of time.